# First entry in my ListView does not appear when set visibility to GONE

Tags: android

Because the code is too huge I can't put it all here. So I just put the basic structures of the classes.

I implemented a custom RelativeLayout as follows:

```
public class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    EditText t1;
    EditText t2;
    ListView l1;
    Button b1;
```

}

The Adapter I used for l1 has an ArrayList list, which contains the messages that I want to show on the l1.

MyLayout is part of the main layout, which is actually another RelativeLayout. On the main layout, there is one Button button and a MyLayout mylayout. button and mylayout are both initialized in the constructor of the main layout. However the visibility of mylayout is set to GONE at first.

When the user press button on the main layout, mylayout is first set to VISIBLE. Then several Message are generated and added to the ArrayList of the adapter. The weird thing is that the first Message is never shown on the ListView. However, if at first I set the visibility of mylayout to VISIBLE not GONE, then every is right. Any ideas why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: There's not enough here to understand where the problem is.

Comment: this may due to some problem in coding. Atleast provide some bit of code perhaps of button which user presses.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you display any layouts at runtime don't forget to add the `LayoutParams`. If you don't add it will corrupt the UI alignments. Also, if you are adding any `RelativeLayouts` at runtime you need to `addRules` like `RelativeLayout.ABOVE`, `RelativeLayout.BELOW` etc to place the views properly on the screen.